# Cannot convert value of type (CMAccelerometerData!,NSError!)->() toCMAccelerometerHandler(aka(Optional<CMAccelerometerData>,Optional<NSError>)-<())

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -2)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2

    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(OperationQueue.currentQueue!) { (data:CMAccelerometerData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if let accelerometerData = data {
            let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
            self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75 + (self.xAcceleration * 0.25))
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to fix it, when I just click 'fix-it' it doesn't work

Comment: Remove both `?`s.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're tricked by XCode, that bothers me as well (The "Fix-it" actually didn't fix it).

In your case, you're missing the `to:` and `withHandler:`

Following are working code with `Swift3.0.2` and `XCode 8.2.1` under `iOS 10`

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(
  to: OperationQueue.main ,
  withHandler:{ (data : CMAccelerometerData?, error : Error?) in
    if let accelerometerData = data {
        let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
        self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75 + (self.xAcceleration * 0.25))
    } 
})
```